# What if I transfer mainnet tokens to an xDai address?

Tags: tokens, sidechain, xdai

What if I transfer mainnet ERC-20/721/1155 tokens or ETH to an xDai address?

Transferring to a different blockchain generally doesn't work, but xDai has a token bridge. Will it work for xDai?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to move USDC from ETH mainnet into xDai via https://omni.xdaichain.com/.
here are some guides:
https://docs.tokenbridge.net/eth-xdai-amb-bridge/multi-token-extension/ui-to-transfer-tokens/transfer-erc20

keep in mind that you will need to pay fees in ETH first to establish the contract to enable the transfer (I paid around $10 in ETH) and then pay another fee for transfer to xDai network (I paid around $40 in ETH). Hope it helps!

Comment: It isn't an answer to my question.